# Passing a personalize string in RetrieveRequest to get the data from DataExtesnion

Tags: marketing-cloud, filters, dataextensions

I am trying to use the filter part and  Retrieve Request to get the data from data extension.

```
RetrieveRequest request1 = new RetrieveRequest();
                request1.ObjectType = "DataExtensionObject[Name of Data Extesnion]";
                request1.Properties = array;
                SimpleFilterPart sfp2 = new SimpleFilterPart();
                String[] sfp2Values = { End.Text };
                sfp2.Property = "EmailAddress";
                sfp2.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
                sfp2.Value = sfp2Values;
                request1.Filter = sfp2;
                status = client.Retrieve(request1, out requestID1, out Results1);
```

I want to pass a pass a personalize string (from textbox)instead of hard coded data extension name.

```
request1.ObjectType = "DataExtensionObject[DETextbox.text]";
```

Is it possible I can do that? If yes how?
I tried this way and it isn't working for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to do this:

RetrieveRequest request1 = new RetrieveRequest();
                request1.ObjectType = "DataExtensionObject[" + DataExtesnionName + "]";